# Non-trivial bin-packing instance with 5 objects.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, contest-math

Bin packing problem is a problem, where one has to find the minimum number of bins of size $v$ required to store $n$ objects of sizes $s_1, \ldots, s_n$. Object sizes are never greater than $v$.

For example, if $v = 10$ and the objects sizes are $2, 5, 4, 7, 1, 3, 8$, we can store objects with 3 bins: $[8, 2], [7, 3], [5, 4, 1]$, but not with 2 bins or less, as this would leave some items unpacked. Therefore 3 is the minimum number of bins required, and $[8, 2], [7, 3], [5, 4, 1]$ is an optimal solution.

The best-fit-decreasing heuristic is a packing strategy, which aims to produce a packing close to optimal. It first sorts all the items in descending order. Then it iterates over all items, and for each item attempts to find an existing bin, which can both fit the item and whose spare capacity is closest to the size of the item. If such bin exists, it puts the object in the bin. If it doesn't, it creates a new bin and puts it there.

A non-trivial bin-packing instance is an instance of the problem, which can't be optimally solved by the best-fit-decreasing heuristic.

For example, the instance $v = 7$, $n=6$ where sizes are $3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2$ is non-trivial, because the best-fit decreasing heuristic will:

1. Sort the items to give $3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2$
2. Put the first two items in the first bin, producing a bin $[3, 3]$
3. Put the next three items in the second bin, producing a bin $[2, 2, 2]$
4. Put the last item in the third bin, producing a packing $[3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2]$

This is a valid packing, but non-optimal, as it requires 3 bins, and there exists a valid packing with two bins: $[3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2]$.

Is there a non-trivial bin-packing instance with $n=5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such instance for any $n\le 5$. Indeed, assume to the contrary. Pick the smallest $n$ for which $O<A$, where $O$ is the number of bins in an optimal packing and $A$ be the number of bins in a packing found by best-fit-decreasing heuristic. Enumerate the objects in such an order that $s_1\ge s_2\ge\dots\ge s_n$. Now we use the following simple observations.

If $O=1$ then $A=1$.

Assume that in an optimal packing there exists a bin containing only one object. But, since $s_1\le v$, without loss of generality we may assume that the bin contains Object 1 and the other objects placed into the first bin by best-fit-decreasing heuristic. Removing these objects from the object list, we reduce the problem to a smaller number of objects, which  contradicts the minimality of $n$.

The above observations imply that $O=2$, because otherwise since $n<6$ in each optimal packing there exists a bin containing only one object. Now fix and optimal packing and consider a bin containing Object $1$. If the bin contains at lest two other objects then it can be easily checked that $A=2$. If the bin contains at most one other object $i$ then the other bin contains all remaining objects. Then in the packing created by best-fit-decreasing heuristic the first bin contains at least Object $1$ and Object $j$ with $j\le i$, so the second bin contains all other objects, because it is able to contain them, so $A=2$.

Comment: Apologies, but I'm having difficulties understanding your proof:

"Assume that in an optimal packing there exists a bin containing only one object. But, since $s_1≤v$, without loss of generality we may assume that the bin contains Object 1 and the other objects placed into the first bin by best-fit-decreasing heuristic."

Is the following a valid counterexample to what you're proposing: `v=7`, `packing = [3, 3], [2]`. Clearly this is an optimal packing. There is a bin, which contains only one object. But that bin does not contain object 1.

Comment: It is a minor nit-pick, but in the first sentence you clearly do not assume the converse, you assume the opposite.

Comment: Also $s_1 ≥ s_2 ≥ ⋯ ≥ s_5$ is should be $s_1 ≥ s_2 ≥ ⋯ ≥ s_n$, where n is the index with the smallest counterexample.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz: v=7, packing = [3, 3], [2] is not a counter example. Without loss of generality you can assume that s1 is in the bin containing only one bin. Because if we have [s1,...] ans [si] as in your example, we can always interchange s1 and si. s1 can replace si because [s1] is valid, because s1<=v. And si can replace s1 because [si,...] is valid, because of si<=s1. So you can tranform you packing to [3], [2,3], which is th packing generated by the adaptive strategy.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz yes, $s_1 \ge s_2 \ge \ldots \ge s_n$ is the correct notation.

Comment: Thanks @miracle173, how about `v=6, packing=[3, 3], [2, 2]`? No matter how you swap, you'll always end up with two items in one bin, as having a bin with only one item would imply the other bin has 3 items. In this instance you can't put any 3 items together in one bin due to bin overflow.

Comment: Nevermind, this is not valid, as there isn't a bin containing only 1 object.

Comment: Thanks @AlexRavsky, I'm still having difficulties understanding the minimal counterexample part of your proof. At no point does this part of the proof invoke the number of objects involved, so it should work for any $n$. Consider for example an optimal packing `v = 7`, `packing = [[5, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2]]`. Your argument will rearrange objects to get another optimal packing `[[2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [5]]`.

Comment: Now it's unclear to me which bin you are going to remove. If you remove the last bin `[5]`, you will get a non-offending instance, which will be optimally solved by the best-fit strategy. If you remove the first bin `[2, 2]`, you will get a non-offending instance, which will be optimally solved by the best fit strategy.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz My rearrangement is more subtle. I recall that it not only swaps (if needed) the bin alone object $s_i$ with $s_1$ but also places in its bin the other objects placed into the first bin by best-fit-decreasing heuristic. So for your example the rearranged (optimal) packing will be $[[2, 2], [2, 2], [5,2]]$ or $[[2], [2, 2, 2], [5,2]]$. The last packing is the same as initial, but the rearrangement construction implies that if we remove the bin $[5,2]$ then we reduce $n$. PS. I corrected the other issues you mentioned, thanks.

Comment: @AlexRavsky we reduce $n$, but we no longer end up with an instance where $O<A$, so there is no contradiction. The reduced instance $v=7$, $objects=[2, 2, 2, 2]$ will be optimally packed by the best-fit heuristic. For all we know the instance $v=7$, $objects=[5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]$ could be the minimal counterexample.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz I don’t understand you reasoning. The instance $v=7$, $objects=[5,2,2,2,2,2]$ is not a (minimal) counterexample, because for it $O=A=3$. Using my approach, we keep $O<A$ for the reduced instance because when we remove the filled bin the for the remaining instance both $O$ and $A$ will decreased by exactly $1$. Indeed, $O$ will decrease by at  least $1$ but not more, because this will contradict an optimality of the initial packing; $A$ will decrease by exactly $1$ due to best-fit-decreasing heuristic algorithm.

Comment: Right, my example was bad, because although it had a bin with only one element, it didn't have the property $O < A$. However, consider my original example `v=7, objects=[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]`. Here, clearly $O < A$, since $2 < 3$, as BFD gives [[3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2]]. But swapping as you described, will give us  [[3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 3]]. Deleting the last bin will give us [[3], [2, 2, 2]], which doesn't decrease $O$, which stays at $2$, but decreases $A$ by one, which goes to $2$. Then we have $O = A$, which means no contradiction.

Comment: The reasoning is pretty simple. For a proof by minimal counterexample, in this case, you need 2 things: 1. A counterexample of size $n$ with $O < A$ 2. From the first counterexample you need to derive another counterexample of size $n-1$ with $O < A$. As I've demonstrated, your derived counterexample may not always have both of these properties with the simple or more subtle swapping that you've given. In the particular instance I've given, you'll need to pick up things from all three bins in order to reduce $n$.

Comment: For example, you'll have to somehow transform [[3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2]] into [[3], [2, 2], [3, 2, 2]], and then delete the last bin. But this is a far cry from "just add more stuff from the first bin".

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz I still don’t understand. Your original example does not admit an optimal packing with a bin having only one object, which is required for the case considered in the third paragraph of my answer. I agree with 1 and 2 and in my previous comment I explained why the counterexample derived  from a given *optimal* packing after a subtle swapping is OK, contradicting the minimality of $n$.

Comment: Of course, you're right. The minimal counterexample part of the proof is perfect. It's just written really tersely and I got confused.

Comment: In the second part of the proof, I understand this part "If the bin contains at most one other object i then the other bin contains all remaining objects. Then in the packing created by best-fit-decreasing heuristic the first bin contains at least Object 1 and Object j with j≤i, so the second bin contains all other objects, because it is able to contain them, so A=2."

Could you enlighten me as to why "If the bin contains at lest two other objects then it can be easily checked that A=2." I can see that this for example wouldn't work with $v=7$ $objects=[[3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 2]]$.

Comment: But clearly there must be something which makes it work if there are less than 6 bins. I'd like to an extended explanation of why "If the bin contains at lest two other objects then it can be easily checked that  A=2"

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz Yes, here I skipped this check because it can be easily done but has a rather long explanation, so I replace it by the following arguments. Clearly, in this case $s_1+s_4+s_5\le v$. On the other hand, Objects $1$, $2$, and $3$ are packed into two bins, so $s_2+s_3\le v$. These inequalities easily imply that $A=2$. Indeed, if BFD algorithm places in the first bin Object $1$ and (at least) one of Objects $2$ and $3$ then since $s_2+s_4+s_4\le v$ it places all remaining objects into the second bin and even partially in the first bin, if this is still possible.

Comment: If BFD algorithm places in the first bin none of Objects $2$ and $3$ then it places them into the second bin, so it places the remaining Objects $4$  and $5$ into the first bin. In all considered cases, $A=2$.

Comment: That's perfect. It's a neat proof.

Answer (score 0):

Define a set of objects $x_1,x_2, ... ,x_k$ to dominate a set of objects $y_1,y_2, ... ,y_l$ if $k\ge l$ and $x_i\ge y_i$ for $1\ge i\ge l.$ If set $X$ dominates set $Y$, then the existence of a solution with $n$ bins for $X$ implies a solution with $n$ bins for $Y$.

Now suppose there to be a solution with fewer bins {$A_i$} than the first-fit solution and let $B_1$ be the first bin in the first-fit solution. The contents of $B_1$ cannot be dominated by the contents of any $A_i$ by definition of the first-fit algorithm. Furthermore, the contents of $B_1$ cannot  dominate  the contents of any $A_i$, for if it did then the objects remaining for the other $B_i$ would be dominated by those remaining for the other $A_i$ and we would have another  non-trivial bin packing with fewer objects and we can restrict this analysis to that smaller example!

Let $A_1$ be a bin containing the largest object $s$. Now  $B_1$ must, of course, contains $s$ and the non-dominating result means that $B_1$ must contain at least two objects. The non-dominating result then means that each $A_i$ must contain at least three objects and this is why $n$ must be at least 6.

Comment: "The contents of B1 cannot be dominated by the contents of any Ai by definition of the first-fit algorithm." Of course it can. If A1 and B1 contain the same elements, then B1 is dominated by A1. Why should A1 and B1 contain different objects?

Comment: "the contents of B1 cannot dominate the contents of any Ai" if A1 adn B1 contain the same objects then B1 dominates A1

Comment: your definition of dmination is not precise. I think you shoud add that x1,x2,... and y1,y2,... are non decreasing sequences. Otherwise a set counld be dominated and not dominated at the same time.

Comment: If the bins A1 and B1 contained the same elements then there would be the reduction to fewer objects described in my solution. Furthermore there is no need for the suggested ordering of the objects.

Comment: But you wrote in your answer "cannot be dominated [...] by definition of the first-fit algorithm" which is worng, so it would be fine if you  repair your answer. 1,2,3 is dominated by 2,3,4 but 3,2,1 is not dominated by 2,3,4.  But 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 are the same set. So the set is dominated and not dominated by 2,3,4. That does not look good.

Comment: Hi @S.Dolan, thanks for looking at this. In the problem statement I'm not asking about first-fit heuristic, but about best-fit-decreasing heuristic. These two are certainly distinct. Here's a good description of first-fit-decreasing and best-fit:

http://bastian.rieck.ru/uni/bin_packing/bin_packing.pdf

In the paper there's no description of best-fit-decreasing, which only differs from best-fit by ordering all objects before packing them.

Comment: I agree with @miracle173. As stateted dominance is not well-defined. The example he gave simulatenously dominates and doesn't dominate.

Comment: To clarify. The contents of one  bin dominate those in another bin if there is an arrangement (any arrangement) such that ... as before. If one wanted to put more detail in then one might wish to define strictly dominate to not allow equality - this might make the proof easier to understand.

Comment: In my rapidly typed answer I also should not have sloppily written 'first-fit'.